# how to create PIXI.text with background image

Tags: canvas, pixi.js

I'm using [PIXI](http://pixijs.github.io/docs/) and I want to add some text objects with background images.

```
var text = new PIXI.Text('my custom text',
    {
      font : '12px Arial',
      fill : 0x666666,
      align : 'center',
      cacheAsBitmap: true, // for better performance
      height: 57,
      width: 82
    });

stage.addChild(text);
```

Is `PIXI.texture` the only way to add background image (like a baloon) to this text?
If so, using the below code:

```
var texture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("balloon");
text.setTexture(texture);
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of null
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not set a background image on a Text Object. But you can easily add the Text Object as a child of a Sprite.

NOTE: A Texture stores the information that represents an image, but it cannot be added to the display list directly. You should use PIXI.Sprite instead.

```
//Create the background Image
var sprite = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('balloon');
sprite.position.x = 100;
sprite.position.y = 100;
stage.addChild(sprite);

//Add text as a child of the Sprite
var text = new PIXI.Text('my custom text',
    {
      font : '12px Arial',
      fill : 0x666666,
      align : 'center',
      cacheAsBitmap: true, // for better performance
      height: 57,
      width: 82
    });    
sprite.addChild(text);
```

You can center align everything like so:

```
sprite.anchor.x = sprite.anchor.y = 0.5;
text.anchor.x = text.anchor.y = 0.5;
```